# First letter is number in string

Tags: php

I was trying to find a quick and easy method to check if the first letter in a string is a number. A lot of the functions and methods I've seen on S.O seem over complicated. I'm wondering, would something like this work:

```
is_numeric($string[0]);
```

Comment: You could just test it yourself you know...

Comment: @Andre Backlund what makes you think I didn't test it? I was more concerned about why others had not suggested it as an answer in other questions.

Comment: So it's an answer disguised as a question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An easier way might be:

```
is_numeric(substr($string, 0, 1))
```

It tackles the problem of a possible empty string (that has no first character) by using `substr()`. `substr()` returns `false` in the case of an empty string, and `false` is not recognized as a number by `is_numeric()`.

Answer (score 7):

No, that would not work. You might get "*Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0*" notice. To make it work, add [`strlen()`](http://www.php.net/strlen):

```
if ( strlen($string) > 0 && is_numeric($string[0]) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why that answer is deleted, but the correct answer is

```
 preg_match('/^\d/', $string);
```

Why? Because it provides a *standard* way to query strings. Normally, you have to answer many similar questions in your application:

- does a string start with a digit?
- does it contain only digits?
- does it end with a letter?
- does it contain a specific substring?

etc, etc. Without regular expressions you'd have to invent a different combination of string functions for each case, while REs provide the uniform and standard interface, which you simply reuse over and over again. This is like algebra compared to arithmetic.

Comment: You dont use logarifm to split couple apples between two kids, right? When you code, the simplier - is better, the shorter - is better and the faster is better. REs are not simple, fast and short for usage though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a clean way of doing it, but use [ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit) instead since it only allows the numbers 0 to 9 and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work on empty strings, so you should check the offset prior accessing it:

```
$result = isset($string[0]) ? is_numeric($string[0]) : false;
```

Comment: No it does not, why should it? That's what isset() is used for. Only when `$string[0]` is set, it will be accessed - which is not the case for the empty string.